# Does the EF Core Cosmos DB provider support the new Bulk API for Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, ef-core-3.1

We are using the latest EF Core 3.1 and the Cosmos DB provider. We would like to have bulk inserts into Cosmos DB and do not know if the latest EF Core provider supports the new Bulk API for Cosmos DB.

Does the EF Core Cosmos DB provider support the new Bulk API for Cosmos DB?

We have looked at https://github.com/dotnet/efcore, but have not been able to determine that this is supported.  We have also looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't include the bulk support that is found in the native Cosmos .NET sdk v3. You'll have to use the native .NET SDK v3 to do bulk operations. We have a [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/bulk-improvements-net-sdk/) from April that has more details.

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework does not provide this implicitly but you can get cosmos client from DBContext class and do it explicitly.

Here's example:

```
        CosmosClient cosmosClient = _context.Database.GetCosmosClient();
        Database database = cosmosClient.GetDatabase("PersonalizationOrder");
        Container container = database.GetContainer(typeof(T).Name);
        var data = await container.CreateItemAsync(new Order
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            PartitionKey = "1",
            ShippingAddress = new StreetAddress()
            {
                City = "XYZ",
                Street = "Street, ttt st"
            }
        });
```